# How to setup RAID 5 - Windows Home Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid, software-raid, hardware-raid, windows-home-server

I am planning to install Windows Home Server 2011 on my new mini server. I have 3 x 2TB hard drives and another hard drive for the OS.

I can't find any tutorials on how set up RAID 5 on Windows Home Server (I do not have hardware RAID).

How can I setup RAID 5 software on Windows Home Server? Which would offer more stability/performance: hardware RAID or software RAID?

Comment: Ughhh, that stinks.  They got rid of drive extender.  But I can see why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have not yet done your WHS installation, I would recommend that you consider a linux alternative.

[Mdadm - Software raid made easy](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Overview#Downloading_and_installing_mdadm_-_the_RAID_management_tool).

You really do not want to have 6TB of data locked into a dependency on Drive Extender or some 3rd party raid tool.

Once you've got that sorted set up Samba and your server's good to go. See also [Ubuntu server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The software RAID isn't really supported on Windows Home Server, yes there are some hacks you can do, but it will be mostly broken.  You are not finding many tutorials on how to do it because earlier because Drive Extender was a somewhat better choice for most people.  Drive extender was dropped from WHS 2011, but there are [some alternatives](http://pricklytech.wordpress.com/2011/02/16/windows-home-server-2011-third-party-drive-extender-replacements/) that are available.

Comment: Are you really set on using WHS or would you consider alternatives?